# Who are my uncle's parents to me, if my uncle is related by marriage?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

For a blood relative, your uncle's parents are your grandparents. What do you call an uncle's parents if he's related by marriage? Step-grandparents?  Grandparent-in-laws?

Comment: Ask them what they’d like you to call them.

Comment: So this is your aunt's parents-in-law? And the only link to you is her marriage to the chap who became your uncle? If that's correct, English has no word for such a distant relation.

Comment: I've always wondered if you can stretch "great aunt/uncle" here. Add a "once removed" here and there. But the most "legit" thing I can think of is "my aunt's in-laws".

Comment: The parents of my uncle by marriage are nobody to me.  They're the in-laws of my aunt, specifically my aunt's mother-in-law and father-in-law, but they are not my in-laws.

Comment: There probably isn't a universal term for this. I had a lot of aunts and uncles, and was always told to address my aunts' and uncles' in-laws as "Mr./Mrs. X"; whatever surname they happened to have.

Comment: Any relative whose relationship to you does not have a specific name is a 'cousin' (first cousins and second cousins are names for specific relationships) and a cousin who is of a different generation is said to be 'removed' by the number of generations between you. Also someone who is a relative only by marriage and is not a _in-law_ is a 'cousin by marriage'. Your aunt's in-laws are, therefore, your _cousins by marriage twice removed_.

Answer (score -1):

My aunt's parents let me call them grandma and grandpa or great aunt and great uncle. Also my uncle Eddie's parents let me call them the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

How about great uncle (or aunt) by marriage?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you asking us?